# In Codename One which is supported either GCM or FCM?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, codenameone

As per this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq), FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. In Codename One, which is supported? GCM or FCM?

Comment: What is your use case for Firebase?

Comment: I am using GCM for push notification . Should I change to FCM for push notification ?
Can I continue GCM for the notification ?

Answer (score 3):

We currently use GCM internally. We can switch to FCM but there is no real reason. Google has no intention of removing GCM as FCM (and a lot of apps) depend on it.

They are pushing FCM to push firebase. This provides no advantage to Codename One users as the easier API isnt' relevant (we abstract away the pains of GCM).

Bottom line is that you don't need to worry, if there is a need to switch to FCM we will do it for you and it will be seamless.

Comment: Nice. Didn't notice there was already an answer when I was drafting. I wanted to ask if you guys have a more recent Video Guide than the other one I linked in my answer? I've *googled* around but didn't really find anything. Cheers!

Comment: I think we practically typed together ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with Codename One so I decided to go ahead and look into their site. I found this [Codename One page](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-push-notification-send-server-push-messages.html) that guides about Push Notifications, but noticed that it's an old guide since this was still using the Developer Console when generating the Server Key (used for GCM/FCM).

With that, I went ahead and asked the Codename One chat support (lower-right side of the page). Chat history below:

**Me**:

> Hey guys. I was wondering what Push Notification Services do you Support? 
>   I've seen this link -- https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-push-notification-send-server-push-messages.html 
>   Do you have your own Push Notification Service? Or are you guys using GCM? Is it already integrated with FCM too?

**Lianna** (Chat Support):

> Hi,
>   we use the native push notifications for the respective platforms GCM, Firefox, Chrome, Microsoft and ipns.
>   Currently we use GCM and not FCM as the advantages given by FCM are mostly for API usage (which isn't applicable) and not very portable (available only for Android). When/if we switch to FCM this would be seamless thanks to our abstraction of the service.
>   FYI that video is a bit out of date, there is more up to date coverage in our developer guide.

Credit goes to Lianna (*Kudos! :)*). I think this [here](https://www.codenameone.com/developers.html) is the developer guide she was referring to.